# Changelog and changes version for .Net Winform App

Tags: c#, winforms, version, changelog

I am making simple WinForm application and I want to ask what is best practice to changes version in properties. When I should change Major, Minor, Build or Revision? And I want to share changelog with application so how small changes I should post to it and which I shoudn´t? And what is the best practice that changelog should look like. Just date and changes or other things (I am just 1 author)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the changelog, it depends on whether you want to publish it.

For example, for you, as the developer, it's adviced to put every code change on the changelog. But end users don't need so detailed information, only fixes or changed/new functionality is usefull for them.

About the version numbering; there isn't really one rule about this. But maybe [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) can help you.

Comment: Scott Hanselman posted a link on twitter about versioning: http://semver.org/ Maybe userfull as well!